# Talk of migrating some questions to unix.SE

Tags: discussion, migration

Looking around here, I haven't come across one asking about migrating questions to unix.SE. However, there is currently [a discussion](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389/migrate-ubuntu-specific-questions-to-askubuntu) on that site's meta, regarding the issue. In fact, the site will be launched any day now, and I want to start a discussion on migrating questions that are very generic, the kind where there isn't a single mention of Ubuntu, like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3592/how-to-configure-partitions-across-two-physical-drives). I say this because unix.SE audience could benefit from this influx, while Ubuntu users have *only* one more site to learn about.

Note that the question is not about [what questions should be asked here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/47/how-do-we-tell-if-a-question-belongs-here-or-rather-at-stackoverflow-superuser), but about *should non-Ubuntu-specific questions be migrated to unix.SE?*

Comment: There are three mentions of Ubuntu in [*that question*](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3592/how-to-configure-partitions-across-two-physical-drives).

Comment: @oli But if you simply replaced 'Ubuntu' with 'Fedora' or 'Solaris', it would equally be valid, as evidenced by the answers.

Answer (score 9):

Ultimately I'm going to say no, but this is just me. Furthermore I will go so far as to say *they* shouldn't migrate to us. Said user has come to X site (where X = [Unix, Ubuntu]) to ask a question because they feel more comfortable asking there. Leaving a comment on either with a sign post that "Hey Y site exists, you could try there" is what we have been doing with programming questions or server questions here.

Forcing a user to have a question answered on another site because it *fits* better there is the wrong stance to take. It is much better to reserve the migration option for content and questions that are purely off-topic and belong on other SE sites.

Comment: Does this mean you guys don't migrate programming questions to SO? I say this because you say *Forcing a user to have a question answered on another site because it fits better there is the wrong stance to take.*

Comment: @Tshepang If a question is a programming question that fits within the spec of Ubuntu, or the Ubuntu family I don't. This site is for Ubuntu Developers and Users so as I see it - programming questions are in scope. Though, that's a bigger grey area than Unix/Linux vs Ask Ubuntu. However, same applies - signpost saying "You can also ask on StackOverflow".

Comment: I agree. Until SE/SO/etc implements a true single-sign-on with a single profile, I can't advocate something that actively complicates the process of helping people. Perhaps the sites should be more like Reddit (a behemoth with its /r/ subcommunities) but that's another conversation.