# Why not to merge this SE with Unix/Linux?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are we better off with a general “Unix & Linux” stackexchange site?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/149/are-we-better-off-with-a-general-unix-linux-stackexchange-site)

I am using Ubuntu but will crosspost to Unix/Linux 100% of my questions since I can't be 100% sure it is Ubuntu specific.

So why not merge these sections?

Answer (score 1):

Because Unix&Linux is a broad topic and concerns mainly about kernel and shell-scripting in general (in short, the entire **Unix** domain, including Unix-like OSes).

Ubuntu, on the other hand, is a Q&A site for all things Ubuntu i.e. problems, doubts and general help in an attempt to make Ubuntu the one of the best distros of Linux (which it has become).

The differences are philosophical and a bit sentimental(if and wherever applicable) rather than literal.

Also it is Ubuntu's tendency to try to rise above other distros so why not a unique Q&A site.

Comment: Just to conserve user efforts. It is harder to post questions to 2 sections.

Comment: @Dims - it is strongly discouraged to cross-post on U&L as per their FAQ.

Comment: @Dims Then post kernel, programming, etc  questions on U&L. Keep tweaking and feature-info on Ubuntu.

Comment: @fossfreedom, sorry I am interested to get an answer so will crosspost to cover more audience.

Comment: @VedVals it is impossible to distinguish in most cases; suppose my question is about GNOME which relates with both sections? I will crosspost. Suppose my question is about scripting, but my OS is Ubuntu. Why not to post into Ubuntu? I will crosspost. Separation is definitely imaginal.

Comment: @Dims U&L may cover more audience but AU will be the best logical place to ask those as the audience is 100% Ubuntu centric, unlike U&L who would most probably refer you to AU.

Comment: @Dims Yes, there will be some common regions. Post those in both sites. However, you must have an idea on which site you would get better response.

Comment: @VedVals you forgot that I receive many responses even on one site. The one single winner is my choice. So, I will crosspost to make it broader.

Comment: No, you shouldn't do that since it causes logistics trouble. For months and years, crossposting has been frowned upon, since presumably when attempted, it didn't work effectively for the SE community *as a whole*. Also, your last comment didn't make sense to me. If there is a clear winner, why crosspost? With that said, if you can prove to a good number of users at both sites(using clear arguments) that a merge is good, the large support will probably call for a vote.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ What logistics trouble?

Comment: @VedVals There are 78K questions on AU and 17K on U&L. Nobody cal and will scour all of these posts to dupe them now that they share a site.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ True.